# php writing standard about "{}"

Tags: php

I am used to use format 1, but I found a php standard document said that my code is not standard . but not tell why format 2 is better than format 1. any one tell me why?
[image]

Comment: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/11/curly_braces_to.html

Comment: read this http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/PHP+Coding+Standard+(draft)

Comment: "The wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many to chose from"  - Admiral Grace Hopper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro, to be honest its entirely up to you. The pear framework uses it the second way. The majority of the others use the first.

PEAR http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.funcdef.php

Answer (score 1):

Conventions don't necessary have a valid reason and logic they are just the standard practice so that when you use other libraries you are adapting the same as they are